# Making button appearance change to "Pressed" depending on current state in notebook

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, button

I have a three buttons next to each other that set the text justification to left, center or right.  I would like the button to have `Appearance->"Pressed"` when that button agrees with the current justification.  I can't seem to find a way to this. Here's the code...

```
Grid[{Button[
     Grid[{{"---"}, {"--"}, {"---"}, {"-"}}, 
      BaseStyle -> {9, "Label", Bold}, 
      Alignment -> {"Columns" -> {{#}}}, 
      Spacings -> {"Columns" -> {{0}}, 
        "Rows" -> {{-.8}}}], {SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, 
       Cell], SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
       TextAlignment -> #]}, Appearance->"Button"] & /@ {Left, 
    Center, Right}
  }, Spacings -> -1]
```

At first I thought this problem could be solved easily using a `SetterBar[]`.  But I think `SetterBar[]` isn't really made to execute actions, whereas `Button[]` and `ButtonBar[]` are.  I couldn't figure out a way to make it work, that's why I used a grid of buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that is exactly the job for `RadioButtonBar`, you can set actions in the second argument of `Dynamic`, but it may be less convenient to make it look like button.

So if you want to something happen dynamically when certain conditions are met you can straightforwardly say it:

```
Dynamic[If[certainCondition, this, somethingelse]]
```

which in our case is e.g.:

```
Appearance ->  Dynamic @ If[
   SameQ[Left, CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[], TextAlignment]], 
   "Pressed", "Button"]
```

And the full code (with `Evaluator->None` since this action can be done by the FrontEnd alone):

```
Grid[{
  Button[
    Grid[{{"---"}, {"--"}, {"---"}, {"-"}}, 
      BaseStyle -> {9, "Label", Bold}, 
      Alignment -> {"Columns" -> {{#}}}, 
      Spacings -> {
        "Columns" -> {{0}}, 
        "Rows" -> {{-.8}}}
    ], 
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell];  
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], TextAlignment -> #], 
    Appearance -> Dynamic@If[
        SameQ[#, CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[], TextAlignment]], 
        "Pressed", 
        "Button"
    ],
    Evaluator -> None
  ] & /@ {Left, Center, Right}}, 
  Spacings -> -1
]
```

[image: gif]

Comment: when I run your code the alignment shifts but the "left aligned button" stays highlighted

Comment: @Sascha... it's because you have to click on a different cell other than the one containing the button.  Not sure why it does that, but works fine for any other cell.  I noticed the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain You are right, when I select a different cell (than the control cell itself) it works.

Comment: @Sascha and Michael what may trick you is that you can change alignment of the cell that is above the cursor which is between cells but the selection won't reflect that untill you really move the cursor to that cell.

Comment: @Kuba you are right, one has to specifically select the cell as shown in the .gif I added to your answer.

Comment: Can this be done with buttonbar function?  If so, this would bypass creating the outer grid correct?

Comment: @MichaelMcCain I don't think so unless you do `ToBoxes` and modify `Appearance`. Which is not worth it probably.

Comment: I see.  Yes it doesn't seem like the buttonbar function allows you to control the individual "pressed" and "unpressed"  states of each bar.  Although the documentation says that buttonbar has ALL of the same options as button.  I don't think this is true in this application.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelMcCain it has but I don't think you can set them separately :)

Comment: Yes!  My bad.  Just checked.  It does allow "Pressed" for the entire bar but not individually.  It shows in a darker shade of gray... and not blue. Thank you