# Enforcing selection of one checkbox from a group

Tags: dynamic, user-interface

Suppose I have a collection of 3 checkboxes with the restriction you can only have one box checked at anytime. If a box is already checked and the user checks a different box how can automatically uncheck the previous box?

Comment: I'd say it is a task for `RadioButtonBar` but you can use the second argument of `Dynamic` inside your Checboxes to manage events.

Comment: [141239](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141239/5478), [105953](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105953/5478), [133647](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133647/5478) the second one looks like the answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @Kuba These are great too, thanks! Your RadioButtonBar is also a very simple solution.